# Is there a way to prohibit delimiting by ', ' and just delimit the csv file with ',' in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-dataset

I am reading a csv file using scala to populate a Dataset and there I am facing delimiter issue which is due to some of my fields having ',' inside them.

The data is like 
A,B,C(temp, temp1, temp3),D,E

This is for spark Dataset in which I have tried reading a file and then mapping it to dataset schema but it seems not working.

```
SparkSession.read
    .option("delimiter",",")
    .option("header","true")
    .schema(schema)
    .csv(path).as[SampleSchema]
```

I expect it to be delimited properly. I have observed the difference where actual delimiter is ',' and it should not delimit by ', '

Comment: Your file isn't valid CSV. To include commas in a CSV value, the field should be enclosed in quotes: `A,B,"C(temp, temp1, temp3)",D,E`. You can load your file as a text file and do the splitting manually.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned, quotes should be used in CSV files. If that is not an option, it is quite doable by using a negative lookahead regex. Given a CSV file

```
h1,h2,h3,h4,h5
A,B,C(temp, temp1, temp3),D,E
A,B,C,D,E
```

and assuming `|` is not contained in the file (any character can be used)

```
val txt = spark.read
  .textFile(path)
  .map(_.replaceAll(",(?!\\s)", "|"))

spark.read
  .option("delimiter", "|")
  .option("header", "true")
  .csv(txt)
  .show(20, false)
```

Output:

```
+---+---+---------------------+---+---+
|h1 |h2 |h3                   |h4 |h5 |
+---+---+---------------------+---+---+
|A  |B  |C(temp, temp1, temp3)|D  |E  |
|A  |B  |C                    |D  |E  |
+---+---+---------------------+---+---+
```

So we can still benefit from CSV parser features such as header skipping and schema inference if needed.

Comment: instead of replacing with '|', you can just escape all ', ' to '\, '
spark csv reader supports quote and escape characters. (if you can replace the parenthesis with single character quote that would be nicer of course).
see https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrameReader.html#csv-org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset-

Comment: Hi Avi,

I dont think its good way to recognize ", " and replace it. Its sort of patching for this big sized data. What if we really want to escape anything that falls inside parenthesis by considering it inside the field.